# Menu bar icons smaller than they should be

Tags: macos, icon, menu-bar

I've tried replacing the stock menubar icons in both Meteorologist and Butler with icons of the same size as the ones they were to be replacing and in both instances the replacement icons appeared significantly smaller than the originals. Neither enlarging nor reducing the size of the replacement icons had any effect on the tiny size with which they appeared. Meteorologist uses .tiffs and Butler uses .pngs. Completely different icons were used for both apps. Butler even includes a submenu function expressly to allow the user to change the icons.

Can anyone explain to me why my replacement menubar icons are appearing half to even a 1/8 smaller than they should be and how I can fix this?

Comment: First idea: perhaps Butler and Meteorologist honor the [DPI info](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/image-size-resolution.html) within the icon files. Did you create the replacement icons yourself? What app did you use for this?